# Wrong product image on the single product page and the first image of the carousel

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, lightbox

Sometimes when I open a single product page the wrong product image pops up in the main image and the first image of the carousel. This is not every time but randomly. Also the wrong image is not everytime the same.

This is the link:
http://www.asdbmx.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/troy-lee-designs-d2-delta-silver-blue-0.jpg

The good one looks like this:
[Good version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGcUj.jpg)

The wrong one looks like this:[Wrong version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvLbv.jpg)

Does somebody know what causes the problem and how to solve it?
It is really frustrating that sometimes it will work and sometimes it won't

I'm using the latest version of woocommerce and the theme i use is Avada (Also the latest version).

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance.

This is the code of the single-product.php
I hope you can help me out

Code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single products
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>

<?php
get_footer( 'shop' );

/* Omit closing PHP tag at the end of PHP files to avoid "headers already sent" issues. */
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at your website, and has I can't see the backend this is purely hypothetical... Wild guess:

For me it seems like 2 loop messing up each one another. I would say that on your product page (maybe?), you're not resetting the post data `wp_reset_postdata()` or not resetting the query `wp_reset_query()` properly upon finishing the loop. But without any code that's just a wild guess.

It's probably just a stupid mistake that is quickly fixable.

You should consider posting the page source code if you need any help (If you're using woocomerce the problem is probably on the product page).

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/

Comment: Thank you for looking at my question

Comment: I edit the code to my question. I hope you can help me.

Comment: If not, maybe i can make a account in my wordpress so you can look inside?

Comment: Hey again Nick, can you also upload the code from the template part single-product

Comment: Also a bunch of quick questions, did you modified anything in the backend or is it a native issue? Did the issue appeared recently or has it been around since the beginning? Is it a theme or did you hired someone? If it is a theme, what is the theme name? Before the issue did you install any plugins? If yes, what were the plugins?

Comment: I've add a look again. i've loaded each D3 HELMET page a 100 times and i've seen the problem across all of them so it's not specific. Every time the problem occurs, the "wrong image" is the same as the last image of the 3 related helmet at the bottom. So we can assume that the problem come's from here. The other interesting thing is that it seems to only happened for the helmets. I've tried to reproduce the error on the gloves without success. Which is weird..

Comment: As the visual only difference between those two product page is the number of items in the carousel... I would say that the problem is probably coming from an interaction problem between the carousel and the related product. So my question is, is the related product a plugin not native to the theme or initial development?

Comment: After further inspection you're apparently using the fusion page builder plugins so my guess would be that it is a bug related to the page builder itself.

Comment: You should try creating a new helmet category under Helmet > Troy Lee Design called "debug helmets" and add a few "fake helmet" with ONLY 2 pictures to see if the problem is happening. You can delete it after and tell me the result. (Right now we are just trying to understand how the bug happens, I sadly think we can't do much more the that, I wont probably be able to fix it as it's probably related to the plugin you're using but we can maybe go around it).

Comment: On a side note, if you ever change theme, you should try picking one that is not based on ANY plugins, you end up with bugs like this were nobody can do anything. Most of the time theme based on page builders or plugins are unsafe and badly made.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help again!

I’m gonna try it with the new “debug helmets”
And the theme part I know.. but back then I didn’t...

Nowadays I use Divi. It’s faster and no extra plugins needed.
And much easier to add css and javascript.

Thanks for your help again!